# PHP Sign-Up/ Email Verification

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Thanks in advance. 
Below is code from PHPmailer (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) which is giving me a few problems. It works along side this PHP sign-up (http://www.codingcage.com/2015/09/login-registration-email-verification-forgot-password-php.html). I know it works other then the email because the table in the database does recieve the values. I can manually update the table and and allow myself to log-in. It does send out a Error 500 page.

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
{      
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 465;             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username = "EMAIL@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password = "PASSWORD";            
    $mail->SetFrom('robert.m.smith112@gmail.com','Coding Cage');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("robert.m.smith112@gmail.com","Coding Cage");
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->Send();
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file and _read_ what the issue is.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); /* Your email code, blah blah blah */ echo $mail->ErrorInfo;`

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code and/or error we can't really help. Maybe start by checking if the phpmailer class is being loaded.

Comment: Actually your code isn't supposed to work because gmail does not allow less secure apps by default to login. To enable this please visit: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Please don't use my old PHPMailer fork as I've not kept it up to date - get the latest from [the proper repo](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and base your code on [the examples provided with it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps). It always helps to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki) too.